# Spring OAuth2 Authorization Server alternative

Tags: java, oauth-2.0, keycloak, spring-oauth2

Since Spring OAuth2 Authorization Server get deprecated so I want to find another library to replace.
I know there are some alternative authorization server such as KeyCloak, FusionAuth, Gluu... but I can't use them because I need some more customization. I need some alternative libraries as String OAuth2.
Thank for your help!

Comment: were you able to find any solution?

Comment: There is some misunderstanding. My usecase don't need OAuth2.

Comment: But if you want to find a solution alternative to Spring OAuth2 I think Keycloak or Ory Hydra/Kratos are good solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok after lots of investigation and testing other open source solution I chose **Ory Hydra**.

I love the architecture of **Ory Hydra** because it doesn't force you to use any identity management solution.

You can implement your own identity management (registration, login, reset password...) and add **Ory Hydra** on top very easy!

Answer (score 1):

Check this out https://spring.io/blog/2020/08/21/get-the-very-first-bits-of-spring-authorization-server-0-0-1 . it is spring experimental module focusing on authorization server features and released 2 months ago.

As per latest release of 0.2.0 this is production ready. Read more on the [spring blog](https://spring.io/blog/2021/08/19/spring-authorization-server-goes-to-production) for details.

Comment: it's still experimental though. I don't think experimental project should be used for production.